# pass - passing passphrase through commandline

Tags: command-line

Here's info on pass: https://www.passwordstore.org

I would like to pass the passphrase key at the command line

```
echo <passphrase key> | pass show docker-credential-helpers/docker-pass- initialized-check
gpg: cancelled by user
gpg: decryption failed: No secret key
```

How do I pass the passphrase key to pass ?

If I issue the following command

```
pass show docker-credential-helpers/docker-pass- initialized-check
```

It prompts me to enter the  which I do and it work but I want to automate that so that I don't have to wait for the prompt.

Comment: Hi, I'm facing the same problem and the answer below is not wokring for me. Because question was ask ~2 years ago, maybe someone would be so nice and share a different solution?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea to do this as your passphrase is now available in clear text for anyone to see which can compromise all your password.  With that said - try editing gpg.conf (on linux it is usually ~/.gnupg/gpg.conf) and add a line with batch to it.

## Options for GnuPG

batch

Comment: sorry could you explain a little more?  So are you stating that I should add the word "batch" to the ~/.gnupg/gpg.conf file?  What would batch do to the file?

Comment: The pass phrase is to open gpg to decrypt the pass store. The default got gpg is interactive where it will be masked   Batch should allow you to echo it in.